# Access get all tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Is there a way in by sql statement or vba code to return all tables from access file? "I don't know the name of the tables"

like when you want to have all fields in a table you use '*' regardless the names of the fields.

but how to get all tables?!!!!

Comment: -1 for not including the relevant context. You are working in Excel with pivot tables and thus, that context should be in the original question. @Astander has actually correctly answered the question you asked, but it doesn't solve your question because your question didn't describe your actual problem sufficiently completely.

Comment: No what I want is what I ask for regardless if I work from Excel or access or other, my question is clear I ask for sql statement to return all tables from ACCESS database file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will bring back all tables in the MS Access database (including linked tables)

```
SELECT MSysObjects.*, MSysObjects.Type
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE (((MSysObjects.Type)=1)) OR (((MSysObjects.Type)=6));
```

It also inclued Sys tables, so you might want to exclude tables starting with *MSys*

Have a look at

- [Using MSysObjects](http://www.perfectparadigm.com/tip001.html)
- [SELECT "Table" AS [Table],
  MSysObjects.Name, MSysObjects.](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/34933376/select-table-as-table.aspx)

Comment: thanks a lot I got this from your answer ->SELECT MSysObjects.Name
FROM MSysObjects
where  (MSysObjects.Name) Not Like "Msys*" and
MSysObjects.Name not like "Tables"  and
MSysObjects.Name not like "Databases" and
MSysObjects.Name not like "Relationships" and
MSysObjects.Name not like "SummaryInfo" and
MSysObjects.Name not like "UserDefined" and
MSysObjects.Name not like "Forms" and
MSysObjects.Name not like "Reports" and
MSysObjects.Name not like "Scripts" and
MSysObjects.Name not like "Modules" and
MSysObjects.Name not like "SysRel" and
MSysObjects.Name not like "DataAccessPages"
 and it work

Comment: You know this is really great but my problem didn't solve it yet :(, what I want is when my dataSource opened I have all tables inserted automatically in the microsoft query -Query form, any hints to that?

Comment: Where do you wish to use this result, in a list box, on a form, in another query, as a Record Source?

Comment: in Excel go to data menu-> pivot table .......... -> external data source -> press next -> press on get data button -> in the choose data source dialog, pick your data source from the list then press okay-> the Microsoft Query opens now and open query design, and have default table inserted in this board, here I want to have all tables which might be in the database not just the default table and this should be automatically, without any action from the user after Microsoft Query opens, that's it

Comment: OOops, I think I am missing something here, by this I query on MSysObjects table not on all of my tables, I will think again

Answer (score -1):

Depends what kind of database you are running. Many of them support the **SHOW TABLES** command.

Comment: -1 for shooting without aiming -- the MS-ACCESS tag was on the question as originally posted.