# How do I use SQL to "Show tables" in a MS Access database?

Tags: sql, perl, ms-access, ms-access-2007, dbi

I based my code on the answer to the question [Access get all tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076422/access-get-all-tables), but am getting the following error:

> DBD::ODBC::st execute failed:
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access
>   Driver] Record(s) cannot be read; no
>   read permission on 'MSysObjects'.
>   (SQL-42000) at direct.pl line 22.
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access
>   Driver] Record(s) cannot be read; no
>   read permission on 'MSysObjects'.
>   (SQL-42000) at direct.pl line 22.

Here is what I have tried so far. I commented out my first attempt. The current attempt is based on [SELECT "Table" AS [Table]](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/34933376/select-table-as-table.aspx) which astander mentioned in his answer to said [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076422/access-get-all-tables). I get the same error either way. Here is my code, in its entirety:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:ODBC:MutantDB','','') 
    or die 'could not connect to database' . DBI::errstr;

my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT "Table" AS [Table],
             MSysObjects.Name,
             MSysObjects.Type
             FROM MSysObjects
             WHERE MSysObjects.Type =1
             Or MSysObjects.Type=6
             ORDER BY MSysObjects.Name;')
    or die 'could not prepare statement' . $dbh->errstr();


# my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT MSysObjects.*, MSysObjects.Type
#              FROM MSysObjects
#              WHERE (((MSysObjects.Type)=1)) OR (((MSysObjects.Type)=6));'
# ) or die 'could not prepare statment' . $dbh->errstr();

$sth->execute() or die $sth->errstr();

while( my ($name, $type) = $sth->fetchrow()){
    print "name: $name \t type: $type \n";
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off with a schema? http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/T/TL/TLOWERY/DBD-ADO-2.1.readme

Comment: Thanks! Post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a schema?

http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/T/TL/TLOWERY/DBD-ADO-2.1.readme

Comment: Here's a better link to DBD:ADO http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-ADO/lib/DBD/ADO.pm

Comment: Thanks. From one of Sinan Ünür's edits of my posts, I learned that it can be even more concise. Use http://search.cpan.org/perldoc? followed by the module of interest, such as http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD::ADO