# How do I retrieve all tables in a database using SQL in Ms Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [can we list all tables in msaccess database using sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629211/can-we-list-all-tables-in-msaccess-database-using-sql)
>   [How to get table names from access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201282/how-to-get-table-names-from-access)

How do I retrieve all tables  in a database using SQL in Ms Access?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076422/access-get-all-tables

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201282/how-to-get-table-names-from-access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT name
from msysobjects
WHERE type=1 and flags=0
;
```