# Query to return list of tables in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get table names from access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201282/how-to-get-table-names-from-access)
>   [can we list all tables in msaccess database using sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629211/can-we-list-all-tables-in-msaccess-database-using-sql)

Can I create a query that returns the names of all tables in a Microsoft Access database? I have some dropdown lists on a website and one of the dropdowns needs to query my database and return a list of table names so that further dropdowns know which table to query for their respective information.

Comment: possible duplicates: [can we list all tables in msaccess database using sql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629211); [How to get table names from access?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201282); [Access get all tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076422)

Comment: I saw those but neither of them worked unfortunately

Comment: There are three, two are poor, but this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201282/how-to-get-table-names-from-access is far more accurate than your version. You are missing a table type, amongst other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out on my own actually

```
SELECT Name
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE (Name NOT LIKE "MSys*") AND (Type=1 OR Type=6);
```

This one worked for me

Comment: That is not quite good enough, see my comment on the question.